# PHPSTAN: Laravel 9 mutators producing "Access to undefined property" error

Tags: laravel-9, mutators, phpstan

I am trying to store a key into my database and I want it to be encrypted and decrypted.

So I use Laravel 9 mutator: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators

```
protected function privateKey(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn ($value) => Crypt::decryptString($value),
        set: fn ($value) => Crypt::encryptString($value),
    );
}
```

and I accessed it to one of my service class:

```
$provider = Provider::findOrFail($id);
$privateKey = $provider->private_key;
```

However, phpstan throws error saying:

```
Access to an undefined property App\Models\Method|Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection<int,                                
         App\Models\Provider>::$private_key
```

However, when I tried using the old way of mutating and accessing attributes, it worked:

```
public function setPrivateKeyAttribute(string $value): void
{
    if (!empty($value)) {
        $this->attributes['private_key'] = Crypt::encryptString($value);
    }
}

public function getPrivateKeyAttribute(string $value): string
{
    return Crypt::decryptString($value);
}
```

and at this point, I don't have any idea why. is this a bug in the side of phpstan? if not, how can I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Kobayakawa in this post from [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/l9-attribute-not-recognized-by-larastan) helped me to answer this.

You should define the return type and what it allowed to be inserted in the mutator. For your example it should be something like this:

```php
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute<Provider, string>
 */
protected function privateKey(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn ($value) => Crypt::decryptString($value),
        set: fn ($value) => Crypt::encryptString($value),
    );
}
```

In my own example I don't define a 'getter'. But you should still define it, because it will still be returned.

```php
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute<Webhook, array>
 */
protected function webhook(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        set: fn (array $value) => self::createWebhook($value),
    );
}
```